# Convert Full Date as String to Date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion

I have a table with the column `EPDATA`, `varchar(25)` field in the format down below.

[image]

How do I convert this format to `YYYY-MM-DD`?

E.g `2020-12-16`

Comment: Use try_convert()   Example:  Select try_convert(date,'Jun 10 2016 12:00AM')

Comment: Wow, pretty easy, it worked!! I was searching for something like this but only found for Oracle! Please answer my question so I can accept it! @JohnCappelletti

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use try_conver().

FYI: `try_convert()` will return a NULL if the conversion fails.

**Example:**

```
Select try_convert(date,'Jun 10 2016 12:00AM')
```

**Returns**

```
2016-06-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to date datatype and format it like so:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(EPDATE AS DATE) ,'yyyy-MM-dd')
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **FORMAT**

```
Select FORMAT(COLUMNNAME, 'YYYY-MM-dd')
```

Also,By **CONVERT**

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, COLUMNNAME, 23)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the way you want with this query.

```
CASE 
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='Jan' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-01-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='Feb' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-02-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='Mar' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-03-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='Apr' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-04-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='May' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-05-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='June'THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-06-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='July'THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-07-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='Aug' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-08-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='Sep' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-09-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='Oct' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-10-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='Nov' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-11-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
WHEN SUBSTRING(#date,1,3)='Dec' THEN SUBSTRING(#date,8,11)+'-12-'+SUBSTRING(#date,5,6)
END
```